# How to handle different input types with the same actions pythonically?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have written some code that allow both `torch.Tensor` and `np.ndarray` data types.

The functions will perform the same operations but since they are both different APIs for some code, I need to always do an `isinstance` check in order to perform the operation.

An example:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from typing import Union

torch_tensor = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
numpy_array = np.array([1, 2, 3])


def expand(inputs: Union[torch.Tensor, np.ndarray]) -> Union[torch.Tensor, np.ndarray]:
    if isinstance(inputs, torch.Tensor):
        return inputs.unsqueeze(0)
    elif isinstance(inputs, np.ndarray):
        return np.expand_dims(inputs, 0)
    else:
        raise TypeError("inputs must be either a torch.Tensor or a numpy.ndarray")
```

One or two functions with this kind of `isinstance` check is fine, but it is not very "neat" when I add in more functions with the same kind of interface as `expand`. Any tips or design that could handle this more elegantly, so that I do not need to perform the `isinstance` checks in every function.

Comment: I guess the clearest way would be checking the type once and then having separate functions for both pipelines. It's a balancing act between readability and functionality in any case.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, instead of

```
from typing import Union
import random

def add_to_a(value: Union[int, str]) -> Union[int, str]:
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value + 1
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        return str(int(value) + 1)

a = random.choice([0, "0"])

print(add_to_a(a))
```

I would structure the code to something alike this, where each type has a separate pipeline starting from the top level when the variable enters.

```
import random

def add_to_int_a(value: int) -> int:
    return value + 1

def add_to_str_a(value: str) -> str:
    return str(int(value) + 1)

a = random.choice([0, "0"])

if isinstance(a, int):
    print(add_to_int_a(a))
    # Other int type processing
elif isinstance(a, str):
    print(add_to_str_a(a))
    # Other str type processing
```

This is the case mostly if there are going to be **more** of these "Union" functions in the processing pipeline. For one Union here and other there it doesn't really matter personally.

This comes down to *DRY (Don't repeat yourself)* with the abundance of `isinstance` checks in the processing functions if we're following the first example with every operation.

Also worth noting, it could be worthwile to construct classes to help differentiate and group the functionalities if it helps the readability at all.